# Where can I find the linker(ld) in Sun Solaris Studios 12.2?

Tags: linker, sun, sparc, sunstudio

At the moment I am using for linking purposes the pre-installed linker on my SPARC machine
in the following directory:

```
/usr/ccs/bin/ld
```

I wanna compile my application with the Sun Studios Compiler 12.2 and so I would also like to use the linker that should come with this package. However, when checking the bin directory of Sun Studios I can just find a c compiler (cc), but no ld (linker). Anyone an idea where
this has gone and how I can invoke it?

Many thanks,
Mike

Comment: What Solaris version are you using (`cat /etc/release`) ?

Comment: The version of Solaris is irrelevant; the linker is in the standard location, is part of the OS and no different version is provided by the Studio Compiler Suite.

Answer (score 2):

By default (ie, unless you try *very* hard) Studio Compilers will use the version of the linker that is shipped with the operating system as a core (unremoveable) component.

It is *not recommended at all* to try to use the GNU linker on Solaris. There are lots of feature differences between the two.

If you want to delve more into the Solaris linker, read the doco at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E26507/index.html, or blogs from the team - https://blogs.oracle.com/rie and https://blogs.oracle.com/ali.

Answer (score 0):

```
# ls -lh /usr/ccs/bin/ld 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 2012-01-26 05:54 /usr/ccs/bin/ld -> ../../bin/ld
```

`/usr/bin/ld` is in
`pkg:/developer/linker`